# Any other ways to write compact logic in place of the one provided here in C# using foreach or list or dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Hi Here is the logic I would like to re-write in a much compact version. I know its possible but am confused so I am providing the entire logic in very raw expanded version.

```
{
    //unitOfDisplay = "MB";
    keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].RowHeader = "Total MB";

    if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month1 != "-" && keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month1 != toUOM.ToString())
    {
        string fromunit = keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month1;
        //Call converter method
        double outdata;
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month1 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month1.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month1, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month1 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }                                             
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month1 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month1.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month1, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month1 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month1 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month1.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month1, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month1 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
    }
    if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month2 != "-" && keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month2 != toUOM.ToString())
    {
        string fromunit = keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month2;
        //Call converter method.
        double outdata;
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month2 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month2.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month2, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month2 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month2 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month2.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month2, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month2 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month2 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month2.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month2, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month2 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
    }
    if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month3 != "-" && keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month3 != toUOM.ToString())
    {
        string fromunit = keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Month3;
        //Call converter method.
        double outdata;
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month3 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month3.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month3, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Month3 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month3 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month3.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month3, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Month3 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month3 != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month3.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month3, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
        keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Month3 = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
    }
    if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Average != "-" && keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Average != toUOM.ToString())
    {
        string fromunit = keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[UNIT].Average;
        //Call converter method.
        double outdata;
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Average != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Average.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Average, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[TOTAL].Average = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Average != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Average.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Average, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[INCLUDED].Average = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
        if (keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Average != "-" && !(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Average.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
        {
            ConvertDataUnit(keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Average, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out outdata);
            keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo[BILLED].Average = outdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        }
    }
}
```

This case is only for when the unit of Display is in MB, the logic converts the value for month1's total, billed, and included and average from their respective units(which can be in MB, KB or GB) into 'MB'

Then i have to write 2 more similar cases when unit of display is 1. 'GB' and 2. 'KB'

I need help to write a compact logic for this data.

Thanks
Kris!

Comment: You may want to add a description. While the code is not complex, it's a bit longer than most people want to read.

Comment: Agree :) At least is what happened to me :)

Comment: I think a good Linq statement should be able to reduce the above down to a couple of lines. If you place a it in a method you should be able to use the same code for KB, MB, and GB just calculate it in KB and multiply to get MB and GB.

Comment: I have a monthyinfo object in the Keyvalue pair, this object is 2D, in way that the indexes are : 1.TOTAL, 2. INCLUDED, 3. BILLED, AND 4. UNIT 5. Average. AND the other dimension is the month1, month2, month3. So i have vlues for the first dimension ie unit total billed inluded and avearge for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a ton of duplication here.  I don't think LINQ is going to help, but you definitely can make it much simpler.

Start by taking the basic unit of repeated code and making it into a helper function.  Making TOTAL/INCLUDED/BILLED a parameter should be easy.  Making Month1/Month2/Month3/Average a parameter will need some tricks like using a lambda to select which property.

EDIT: But really, I think the best solution is to pick a single unit for internal variables (e.g. kB) and stop all this converting back and forth.  Do just one conversion to create a string for display.  Converting back and forth will lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

Factorize !

It could be like this

```
public void CheckGlobal()
{
    Test(toUOM, keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo, mi => mi.Month1, (mi, val) => mi.Month1 = val);
    Test(toUOM, keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo, mi => mi.Month2, (mi, val) => mi.Month2 = val);
    Test(toUOM, keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo, mi => mi.Month3, (mi, val) => mi.Month3 = val);
    Test(toUOM, keyValuePair.Value.MonthlyInfo, mi => mi.Average, (mi, val) => mi.Average = val);
}

private void CheckProperty(string toUOM, MonthlyInfoArray monthlyInfoArray, Func<MonthlyInfo, string> getValue, Action<MonthlyInfo, string> setValue)
{
    var fromunit = getValue(monthlyInfoArray[UNIT]);
    if (unit != "-" && unit != toUOM.ToString())
    {
        string outdata;
        if (CheckBasic(fromunit, toUOM, getValue(monthlyInfoArray[TOTAL]), out outdata))
        {
            setValue(monthlyInfoArray[TOTAL], outdata);
        }
        if (CheckBasic(fromunit, toUOM, getValue(monthlyInfoArray[INCLUDED]), out outdata))
        {
            setValue(monthlyInfoArray[INCLUDED], outdata);
        }
        if (CheckBasic(fromunit, toUOM, getValue(monthlyInfoArray[BILLED]), out outdata))
        {
            setValue(monthlyInfoArray[BILLED], outdata);
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckBasic(string formunit, string toUOM, string value, out string sOutdata)
{
    if (value != "-" && !(value.ToString().Equals("0.00")))
    {
        double dOutdata;
        ConvertDataUnit(value, fromunit, toUOM.ToString(), out dOutdata);
        sOutdata=dOutdata.ToString("#,###,###.##");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You will gain time, and application size ;)